# The meaning of "unweighty trifle" from "The Prince and the Pauper"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, archaic-language

This is an extract taken from chapter VI, of Mark Twain's book "The Prince and the Pauper". I just can't understand the meaning of "unweighty trifle."

> "I am full loth to word the thing that is in my mind, and thou so
>   near to him in blood, my lord.  But craving pardon if I do offend,
>   seemeth it not strange that madness could so change his port and
>   manner?--not but that his port and speech are princely still, but
>   that they DIFFER, in one **unweighty trifle** or another, from what
>   his custom was aforetime.  Seemeth it not strange that madness
>   should filch from his memory his father's very lineaments; the
>   customs and observances that are his due from such as be about
>   him; and, leaving him his Latin, strip him of his Greek and
>   French?  My lord, be not offended, but ease my mind of its
>   disquiet and receive my grateful thanks.  It haunteth me, his
>   saying he was not the prince, and so--"

Comment: *Unweighty* will not be found in many dictionaries, but words of the form *unX* will almost always mean simply *not X* -- that's why dictionaries don't bother listing them. Look up *weighty* and *trifle*; that should answer your question. If it does not, come back and use the 'edit' button to report what you found, and why you are still puzzled, and we will do our best to explain.

Answer (score 1):

A **trifle** is a small thing of little importance. (See definition 1 or 2 at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trifle) It's also a type of dessert, which is how I remember the definition - a thing of no more lasting weight or importantance than a bowl of cake and a bit of cream.

Weighty means heavy or serious, as in http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weighty.  Therefore, the reverse - **Unweighty** - means something light or trivial.

In context, the character is repeating themselves - the differences in behavior are **trivial matters** of **no real importance**.  This is contrasted with the character's obvious distress about the differences that have led the character to take these concerns to the lord - despite what they say, it seems serious!